# how to configure xamp?

Tags: apache, xampp

recently i installed xamp server on my VPS (windows xp sp3)
and i installed mysite there 
i am successful to run my from 
http://localhost.com/mysite/index.php

and http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/mysite/index.php (locally on my vps ,where xx.xxx.xxx.xx is my server IP )

but when i am trying to access the link http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/mysite/index.php  from my home pc its saying waiiting and finally blank white page coming :(

can any one help me in this issue

thanks in advance

**Edit : Damn i didnt turned off windows firewall ,Problem solved ,If some one faced this issue just turn off u r windows firewall:)**

Comment: You might have more luck asking this at serverfault.com - But to give it a try: does "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" work? To me it looks like there is ne connection between you and the host.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of opening the firewall, edit the httpd-xampp.conf in  xampp\apache\conf\extra folder.

The last rule is there to unallow unexepected navigation on configuration pages.